# "The fullness" vs "fullness"

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

When should one put a definite article before the word "fullness"?

UPD: To be precise, I have the following sentence.

> The first condition is just (the ?) fullness of A.

Here *fullness* is some kind of property. What I also know is that I'd say:

> Here we prove fullness of A.

Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

P.S. I'm also looking for a good consistent English grammar and punctuation book. Would be very grateful for any references.

Comment: Hello Anton. The second question is not really On Topic here. About the first one, can you be more specific and also provide more context? Is there a particular reason why you're asking about the word "fullness"? Where would you need to use it? Edit this info inside your question. :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use *fullness* without the article to refer to the general concept of fullness:

> A pleasant feeling of fullness usually comes after a hearty meal.

Use the definite article to refer to a specific instance of fullness:

> The fullness I felt after the meal was most welcome, as I hadn't eaten for three days.